# Work Item Only View in TFS 2013 Express

Tags: tfs

How do I set up a work item only view in TFS 2013 Express?

There is no such a group built in.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's a license related question. WIOV requires no TFS CAL. I'm wondering how to ensure I'm in line with the license agreement.

Answer (score 1):

"Work Item Only View" has been replaced by a "Limited" view in Team Web Access.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159364.aspx#how_to for more information on how to change it.

If you're not seeing it, it could be that you're not at the root administration page for TFS, or you're not an administrator.  Try going directly to `http(s)://[server]/tfs/_admin/_licences`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to access `Team Explorer`, included in Visual Studio
You must connect by entering `Server Url` , `Team Project Collection` & `Team Project`

You have also easy solution by `Add In On Excel` (Add In Excel is installed with Team Explorer), Open `WIQL query` writetd on your Portal for example

On 2013 you have new organization on your Team Explorer, if you don't find you can use `search engine`

Comment: Work Item Only View is a special kind of permission that allows for accessing TFS without a CAL. It's called Limited Access in TFS 2013 I think. It is shown on some of the articles I've found but it's not there in my Express installation.

Comment: can you send me article ?